# Android Layout: Center CircularProgressBar with Text Above and Below in FrameLayout

Tags: android, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"



    tools:ignore="ExtraText"><![CDATA[
    tools:context= ".MainActivity">


    ]]>

    <com.mikhaellopez.circularprogressbar.CircularProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_circular"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:cpb_background_progressbar_color="@color/purple_200"
        app:cpb_background_progressbar_width="20dp"
        app:cpb_progressbar_color="@color/black"
        app:cpb_progressbar_width="15dp"
        app:cpb_round_border="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv_stepsTaken"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/_0"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="48sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_totalMax"
        android:layout_width="43dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end|center"
        android:text="@string/_2500"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp" />


 </FrameLayout>
```

I'm working on an Android app, and I'm facing an issue with my layout. I have a CircularProgressBar in the center of the screen and two TextView elements. I've managed to center the circular progress indicator (progress_circular) and the first text (tv_stepsTaken), but I'm struggling to center the second text (tv_totalMax) and position it below tv_stepsTaken.

I've tried various combinations of layout_gravity and layout_center* attributes, but I haven't been able to achieve the desired layout.

Could someone please guide me on how to center the tv_totalMax TextView and place it below the tv_stepsTaken TextView while keeping the circular progress indicator in the center of the screen? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Any reason you want to stick to FrameLayout? This might be easier to achieve with a ConstraintLayout. I can help with a layout there if you need :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `RelativeLayout` as your parent layout while maintaining your gravity.

then use the `android:layout_below="@+id/"` to align them. add margin to adjust spacing.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the layout you described with the CircularProgressBar in the center and the two TextView elements, you can use `ConstraintLayout`. Here's how you can achieve that using ConstraintLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:ignore="ExtraText"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.mikhaellopez.circularprogressbar.CircularProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_circular"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:cpb_background_progressbar_color="@color/purple_200"
        app:cpb_background_progressbar_width="20dp"
        app:cpb_progressbar_color="@color/black"
        app:cpb_progressbar_width="15dp"
        app:cpb_round_border="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tv_stepsTaken"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_stepsTaken"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/_0"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/progress_circular"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_totalMax"
        android:layout_width="43dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:text="@string/_2500"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_stepsTaken"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In this way, you can use `ConstructLayout` to set vertical constraints to achieve the desired layout.

Answer (score 1):

The required layout will be much easier to accomplish with `RelativeLayout`.

- Relative Layout helps to align views relative to each other.
- Frame Layout helps to align views on top of each other in layers.

Below is an example using Frame Layout. You can align views with attributes like `layout_below`, `layout_start`, `layout_end`, etc. to align views relative to other views. You can also use `centerInParent` and `centerHorizontal` to align view relative to parent.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_circular"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:cpb_background_progressbar_color="@color/purple_200"
        app:cpb_background_progressbar_width="20dp"
        app:cpb_progressbar_color="@color/black"
        app:cpb_progressbar_width="15dp"
        app:cpb_round_border="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_stepsTaken"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="48sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_totalMax"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_stepsTaken"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="2000"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Sample Output:

[image: Sample Output]